Wrong results for restricted date search via Google Search API for Google Patens
I have been querying Google Patents with via Google Search API with queries like:
Search URL: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=%22heat%22+before:publication:20090101&start=1&filter=1&cx=<my_cx>=<my_key>&siteSearch=patents.google.com
However, the results don't have the date boundary expected, ex. publication before 2009-01-01 in the example above. Why?
I tried changing the position of key=API_KEY&cx=<Your_PSE_ID> and removing "&siteSearch=patents.google.com". Therefore, for a test search with only one exact term ex. "heat" and patent publication date before 2009-01-01 (format YYYYMMDD), the new URL is:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key= API_KEY&cx= My_PSE_ID&q=%22heat%22+before:publication:20090101&start=1&filter=1
where My_PSE_ID = "9543551b8b9da40ed" in my case.
However, I still get the same results that include documents with publication dates after 2009-01-01. The first 10 results that I get are:
patents.google.com/patent/EP0761639A1/fr
Publication date:  1997-03-12
Document date (dc.date):  1996-06-26
patents.google.com/patent/US5019402A/en
Publication date:  1991-05-28
Document date (dc.date):  1990-02-20
patents.google.com/patent/US9314369B2/en
Publication date:  2016-04-19
Document date (dc.date):  2008-01-17
patents.google.com/patent/US8273114B2/un
Publication date:  2012-09-25
Document date (dc.date):  2006-11-03
patents.google.com/patent/EP3337269A1/de
Publication date:  2018-06-20
Document date (dc.date):  2016-08-29
patents.google.com/patent/WO2010117508A2/en
Publication date:  2010-10-14
Document date (dc.date):  2010-02-24
patents.google.com/patent/EP3355645B1/de
Publication date:  2024-06-26
Document date (dc.date):  2016-08-05
patents.google.com/patent/EP2429234A1/zh
Publication date:  2012-03-14
Document date (dc.date):  2010-04-19
patents.google.com/patent/EP3681043A1/fr
Publication date:  2020-07-15
Document date (dc.date):  2019-12-10
patents.google.com/patent/WO2013057690A1/en
Publication date:  2013-04-25
Document date (dc.date):  2012-10-18
